# Negative Damage of an Animal

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The [D&D Wiki](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD%3aRaven) indicates some animals have a negative modifier to their damage such that they can never do positive damage. In this case it's `1d2-5`. How should this be interpreted?

Comment: D&D Wiki is a *terrible* source; they frequently mislabel homebrew as official and vice-versa, copyright infringement is rampant on the site, and there is absolutely no quality control of any kind, leaving a lot of the homebrew material on the site *very* poorly done. For official rules, I recommend [d20srd.org](http://d20srd.org/); for homebrew, I recommend the Giant in the Playground forums or Brilliant Gameologists/Min Max Boards.

Comment: @KRyan SRD stats are the same: `1d2-5`, leaving the question the same.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying in general. If there was a problem with the question itself I would have suggested particular changes, or edited it myself if it was clear what you meant. There wasn't, I just try to recommend that people avoid that site. There are some diamonds in the rough, I'm told, but I've never found one and there's a lot of rough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means they do 1 point of damage on a hit, unless you buff away the negative modifier.

> *[D&D Wiki SRD](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Attack_Damage)*
>
> **Minimum Damage**
>
> If penalties reduce the damage result to less than 1, a hit still deals 1 point of damage.

Comment: Slightly more reliable link to the SRD: either [this](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/combat.html#damage) or [this](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#minimumDamage)  This is also covered in the section on how to read monster entries.

Comment: I went with D&D Wiki because that's what he used in the question.